# Как добавить в хэш ruby новое значения, используя блок с методом?

Tags: ruby, хеширование, методы, словари, замыкания

Как добавить в хэш ruby новое значения, используя блок с методом, как добавлять новое значения в массив, используя метод и блок, я знаю.

```
def dig
 yield "two" 
end
 val=["zero", "one"]
dig do |val1| val<<val1
end
```

Решил написать код, но только хешом, и получил ошибку, подскажите как правильно написать используя блок с методом. Не судите строго я новичок.

```
def dig
 yield "two"=>2 
end
 val=["zero"=>0, "one"=>1]
dig do |val1, key| val<<val1, key
end
```

Comment: dig do |val1, key| key у Вас будет nil, в методе Вы отдаете в yield один параметр с хешем, и смотрите в сторону метода #merge класса Hash

Comment: `val=["zero"=>0, "one"=>1]` -- практически уверен, что вы ждёте совсем не того, что этот код делает на самом деле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вот это выражение

`val = ["zero"=>0, "one"=>1]`

возвратит Вам не хэш, а результат его работы равнозначен:

`val = Array.new(1, { "zero"=>0, "one"=>1 })`

В результате `val` будет представлять собой массив из одного элемента:

`[{ "zero" => 0, "one" => 1 }]`

Во-вторых, значения в хэш добавляются по ключу. То есть, если Вам, например, необходимо в хэш `params` добавить значение `8080` с ключом `port`, то выражение добавление элемента в хэш:

`params['port'] = 8080`

Это значит в блок в методе `dig` надо передать два параметра: ключ и значение. Вы же передаёте один параметр `"two"=>2`. Вы передаёте хэш из одного элемента `{ "two" => 2 }`, а в блоке ожидаете два параметра `val1, key`

Вот пример реализации метода `dig`:

```
def dig
  yield "two", 5 
end

val = { "zero" => 0, "one" => 1 }
dig { |key, value| val[key] = value }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй определить хешь в самом начале, как хэш массивов.

h  = Hash.new([])

И использовать += вместо <<